# Tkinter image doesn't display without matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My code generates an image as a numpy array, and then displays it in a canvas object. I use matplotlib for debugging and when when display the matplotlib window, it seems to work correctly.

However, when I close the matplotlib window, the image object is cleared and becomes fully white.

You can see with both windows open the canvas is correctly displayed. However when closing the matplotlib window, it becomes fully white.

Note: I've tried completely removing the matplotlib calls, and now the image is always white and never displays anything.

[image]

[image]

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

def generate():
    
    # clear canvas
    canvas.delete("all")

    # make clean array
    img = np.ones((width, height, 3), dtype=np.float32) * 0.75

    # randomly generate positions
    x_generated = np.random.uniform(0, width, 5)
    y_generated = np.random.uniform(0, height, 5)
    
    for x, y in zip(x_generated, y_generated):
        base_height = 70
        base_width = 70

        # generate the corners
        x0 = x - base_width/2
        x1 = x + base_width/2
        y0 = y - base_height/2
        y1 = y + base_height/2

        # create rectangle
        poly = np.array((
            (x0, y0),
            (x1, y0),
            (x1, y1),
            (x0, y1),
        ))

        rr, cc = polygon(poly[:, 0], poly[:, 1], img.shape)
        img[rr, cc, :] = 0.5

        # # canvas method. I don't want to use this!
        # canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red", outline="")
    
    # display generated image in tkinter canvas
    scaled_to_8bit = img * 255
    newarr = scaled_to_8bit.astype(np.uint8)
    imgarray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(newarr, 'RGB'))

    # create the canvas image object from the numpy array
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor="nw", image=imgarray)
    
    # display pixel data for debugging
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 1000
    height = 1000

    # Create a root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background="green")

    # Create a canvas widget
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
    canvas.pack()

    # Create a button widget
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate)
    button.pack()

    # start main tk loop
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to maintain a reference to the image for it to continue to exist - store it in a global variable, an attribute of some widget, or whatever.  The matplotlib window was apparently keeping a reference itself, but only for as long as the window was open.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah yes that fixed it! I assumed the canvas automatically kept a reference to the objects drawn on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that when the matplotlib window is closed, the canvas loses the reference to the image, and so the canvas is updated and its blank.

I used a class to organise the code and allow for the reference to the image to be stored nicely

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

class Application:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 1000

        # Create a root window
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.configure(background="green")

        # Create a canvas widget
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Create a button widget
        button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=self.generate)
        button.pack()

        # start main tk loop
        root.mainloop()


    def generate(self):
        
        # clear canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")

        # make clean array
        self.img = np.ones((self.width, self.height, 3), dtype=np.float32) * 0.75

        # randomly generate positions
        x_generated = np.random.uniform(0, self.width, 5)
        y_generated = np.random.uniform(0, self.height, 5)
        
        for x, y in zip(x_generated, y_generated):
            base_height = 70
            base_width = 70

            # generate the corners
            x0 = x - base_width/2
            x1 = x + base_width/2
            y0 = y - base_height/2
            y1 = y + base_height/2

            # create rectangle
            poly = np.array((
                (x0, y0),
                (x1, y0),
                (x1, y1),
                (x0, y1),
            ))

            rr, cc = polygon(poly[:, 0], poly[:, 1], self.img.shape)
            self.img[rr, cc, :] = 0.5

            # # canvas method. I don't want to use this!
            # canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red", outline="")
        
        # display generated image in tkinter canvas
        scaled_to_8bit = self.img * 255
        self.img_8bit = scaled_to_8bit.astype(np.uint8)
        self.photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.img_8bit, 'RGB'))

        # create the canvas image object from the numpy array
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.photoimage)
        
        # display pixel data for debugging
        plt.imshow(self.img_8bit)
        plt.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")
    app = Application()
```